# Pass a flask variable from javascript to html

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I try to programmatically  generate a html div in JavaScript and add it into my html page when a button is clicked. Everything works pretty well except that my variables coming from Flask are not displayed.

Example :

Javascript :

```
function add_div(){
    var html_to_add = "<div><p>{{my_string}}</p></div>";
    $(html_to_add).insertBefore("#submit-btn");
}
```

Python :

```
@app.route("/")
def main_page():
    return render_template("index.html",my_string="Variable à afficher")
```

When the button is clicked in html, it displays : `{{my_string}}` instead of "Variable à afficher".

Is there a way to displays the variable correctly ?

Comment: Can you try this `var html_to_add = str("<div><p>" +{{my_string}}+"</p></div>"); `

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately, even if I put the javascript code into a `<script>` tag. Here is the screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/h91t8.png

Comment: Did you put the value of `my_string` directly?

Comment: Try these lines `var my_str = '{{ my_string }}';` and `var html_to_add = "<div><p>" + my_str + "</p></div>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
var my_str = '{{ my_string }}';
var html_to_add = "<div><p>" + my_str + "</p></div>";
```

Comment: It works perfectly, even with Jinga expression! Thanks a lot @Arihant

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var html_to_add = `<div><p>${my_string}</p></div>`;
```

Pay attention to the punctuation mark `, it is backquote.